# Google scripting: return value instead of formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I made a script:

```
function getWN8() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var startRow = 11;
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
  var input, cellFunction, range, row;


  for (var n=startRow-1; n < values.length;++n){
    input = values[n][0];
    row = values[n];
    cellFunction = '=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://en.wot-life.comeu/player/' + input + '", "table", 1),16,2)';

    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; ++i) {
        range = sheet.getRange((n+1), 2);
        range.setValue(cellFunction);
    }
  }
}
```

This script is reading values from first column, insert value from first column to http link and output is pushed into cells in 2nd column. But If I look in sheet, I have displayed numeric value in cell, but it is threated as an formula. Therefore I can't set conditional formatting.

So all I need to do, is to push value to the cell instead of formula. How can it be done ? I'm not very skilled in scripting, or programming.

Thanks for any help

Ivo

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use **`setFormula(formula)`** or **`setFormulaR1C1(formula)`**.

> [**`setFormula(formula)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
>
> - Updates the formula for this range. The given formula must be in A1 notation.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
cell.setFormula("=SUM(B3:B4)");
```

> [**`setFormulaR1C1(formula)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula)
>
> - Updates the formula for this range. The given formula must be in R1C1 notation.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
// This sets the formula to be the sum of the 3 rows above B5
cell.setFormulaR1C1("=SUM(R[-3]C[0]:R[-1]C[0])");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doc link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LVlRhOQRkGNIB8-fcZzzK4AneQ5PYlse49EkY9Pd3HE/edit?usp=sharing ned to get sum of B11:B111 but there are no values to sum :(

Answer (score 0):

To turn the formula into a value you will have to add something to your last iteration like:

```
var val = range.getValue;
range.setValue(val);
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way calculate and put in the value directly by using a spreadsheet formula. To put in the value directly, it would require a code that is executing exactly the same math as the formula.