# Lookup value from cell on specific date, then keep that value indefinitely

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

[image: Range containing numerical value needed]

[image: Destination Range]

I am looking for a formula that: on 6/14/19, lookups up "Ige" in another column and grabs the numerical value. Once numerical value found, keep ONLY that value indefinitely. These are odds for betting that are constantly changing, so I want to grab only those specific odds on that specific day and put it into the box next to the date.

I know how to setup vlookup, but not sure how to do it on a specific date and only keep the value from that date.

Comment: Sure, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NA1BJJdtSEf0Gj0TCQCjkb_0gNQzvmYsZODfmpMLRTo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: _lookups up "Ige" in another column and grabs the numerical value_ Would you please expand your question to identify the "other column" that it should look up and the location of the "numerical value" that it "is meant to grab..And, when on the "6/14/19" do you expect this to happen, at the beginning of the day, noon, end of day? On a tangent, what work have you done (successful or otherwise) to develop,a script to do get the data and convert it to a value.?

Comment: Hey ted, this is a better way to explain my question.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NA1BJJdtSEf0Gj0TCQCjkb_0gNQzvmYsZODfmpMLRTo/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to the script to do the following: If today is 6/14/19 (yellow highlighted date), then find "Ige" (red highlighted date) in sheet, then copy and paste the numerical value associated (cyan highlighted) into the destination (green highlighted cell). I only want a numerical static value once the script runs. I'd want the date to be referenced by what I have currently, and run daily.

Comment: [Google scripting: return value instead of formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40012708/1330560) might be a helpful topic.

Answer (score 0):

#### Requirement:

Copy data matching dates to another range.

---

#### Solution:

```
function copyData() {
  //spreadsheet variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //data variables
  var raw = sh.getRange('W30').getDisplayValue();
  var range = sh.getRange(71, 17, 6, 2); //row 71, column R, for 6 rows and 2 columns
  var data = range.getDisplayValues();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'M/dd/yy');

  //loop through range
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //if date on sheet matches today's date
    if (data[i][0] === date) {
      var val = raw.toString().replace(/\+|-/g,''); //remove '+' and '-' from data
      sh.getRange(71+i, 18).setValue(val); //set value
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

The script will loop through your range and compare the date in the column to the current date, then if they match it'll copy the value to the correct row in your range.

You will need to change `var range` if you want to record any more than 6 days worth of data, this is easy enough though, just change the '6' to however many rows worth of data you want to keep.